# How Can You Clear/Reset or Default the Selected Debug Config in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have multiple debug/run configurations setup for my project in Visual Studio Code. How can I ensure a specific configuration is the default selected when opening the project?

If I select one, when I close VS Code it remains the default selection after re-launching the project. For *reasons* I need to default to a specific configuration every time the project is opened.

**Example launch.json**

```
        "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/www"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Port",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Mocha Tests",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "args": [
                "-u",
                "tdd",
                "--timeout",
                "999999",
                "--colors",
                "${workspaceRoot}/test"
            ],
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        }
    ]
```